# Copying a folder to another disk in python

Tags: python, file-system

I have made this code to copy a folder to another disk, and it works, but I think there is a better way.

If don't use the `replace()`, it says the folder exists and it is correct.  The 'T': is real. Can someone point me to the right path?

The `folder_path` is the path for the torrent folder. it is a normal path, like: `'D:/FILES/MYFOLDER'`. The `file_path` is a variable as to make a torrent, if a folder=folder_path, if a file=file_path, but its not important for the question.

```py
folder_path = 'D:/FILES/MYFOLDER'
file_path = ''
```

```
src = folder_path
folder_path_copy = folder_path.replace('D:/FILES/', '')
destination = 'T:' + folder_path_copy
logging.info('Copying files')

if file_path == '':
    shutil.copytree(src, destination)
    logging.info('Folder copied')
else:
    pass
```

Comment: I have clean the inicial code to improve it.

Comment: Please do not edit the question, especially the code, after an answer has been posted. Changing the question may cause answer invalidation. Everyone needs to be able to see what the reviewer was referring to. [What to do after the question has been answered](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers).

Comment: sorry, thank you, can i improve the code in awnser below it?

Comment: folder_path is "D:/FILES/SOMEFOLDER", file_path as nothing to do with the question, because if folder_path is present file_path is not.

Answer (score 1):

We can simply copy any folder to any disk by using `shutil.copytree()` function. I think the name you are using to copy your folder to disk T already exist. So check that.
I copied one of my folder from disk C to disk D with following lines of code without using replace() function.
Here's the code:

```
import shutil

# your source and destination path could be different

src = 'C:\\Users\\Lenovo\\PycharmProjects\\practice\\invitations'
destination = 'D:\\invitations'
shutil.copytree(src, destination)
```

The above code successfully copies the invitations folder in disk D.

Comment: This is what i have.

Comment: And it gives an error "folder is present".

Comment: Which IDE are you using?

Comment: Visual studio code.

Answer (score 1):

1. Your code is broken, since it has uninitialized variables.
2. Your empty `else` block is redundant and can be removed.
3. You can use `pathlib` to calculate the relative paths.

```py
from logging import info
from pathlib import Path
from shutil import copytree

src_dir = Path(r'D:\FILES\my_folder')
relpath = src_dir.relative_to(r'D:\FILES')
dest_dir = Path('T:') / relpath
info('Copying files')
copytree(src_dir, dest_dir)
logging.info('Folder copied')
```

Comment: This work, but i feel its not very different about my solution. I will study it.